# How to read a local text file using javascript

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a button in in view page. On clicking the button an function gets called.In that function am calling another function with location of file as parameter.In the second function i need to read the file specified in the location passed and show the contents in console.What i already tries is below

```
ReadFile : function(){
        this.ReadTextFile("C:\Users\RFRANCIS\Downloads\Inv00008W.txt");
    },
ReadTextFile: function(file)
    {
        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
            {
                if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                {
                    var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                    alert(allText);
                }
            }
        }
        rawFile.send(null);

    }
```

But I am getting Access denied error.Please find me to solve this issue or suggest another method.I am testing this in IE11.

Comment: The path, write it correctly, without escaping the first letters of the items in the path.

Comment: this.ReadTextFile("file:///C:\Users\RFRANCIS\Downloads\Inv00008W.txt");
Is it like this?

Comment: The "separator" in an url path is not a backslash ... A backslash is an escaping character in JS, it escapes the character next to it.

Comment: i corrected it and gave as 
this.ReadTextFile("file:///C:/Users/RFRANCIS/Downloads/Inv00‌​008W.txt");
But I got Access Denies error.How can i fix it?

Comment: Looks like item 3 in Elemental's answer -> not possible.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access you local drive you need a valid URL for the file which probably looks more like `file:///c:/` than what you have but you have a few overlapping issues here:

1. The url for a local file must start with file:///
2. You need to understand about escape characters and slashes in Javascript string literals (you need special syntax to express slashes in javascript)
3. When you fix these you are still going to get CORS security exceptions because (at least chrome) doesn't perceive local files as one domain. (To resolve this you either need to set you chrome up specially or use a proper localhost http-server on your local machine.

Comment: @Teemu thx, interesting - I'm  not strong on sapui functionality